# Discontinuity and imaginary part of the logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I have to solve the QFT integral $$\Pi(p^2)=\int_0^1dx\log\left(\frac{m^2-x(1-x)p^2}{4\pi}\right)\big(x(1-x)\big)$$ using the [Optical Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_theorem), which means I want to find the imaginary part of $\Pi$, which will be nonzero between the roots of the argument of the log $x_+$ and $x_-$ if $p^2>4m^2$: what I don't get is why on my lecture notes I have written that $i\Im(\Pi)=\text{Disc}(\Pi)$ where $\text{Disc}$ is the discontinuity of the fuction when crossing the branch cut (so $2\pi$): $$i\Im(\Pi)\stackrel{?}{=}\text{Disc}(\Pi)=2\pi i\int_{x_-}^{x_+}\big(x(1-x)\big)$$ I think the imaginary part should be $\pi i \int \dots$, since $\log(z)=\log(\rho)+i\theta$ and (between $x_+$ and $x_-$ if $p^2>4m^2$) one has $\theta=\pi$. Are my lecture notes just incorrect?